ULN2003 stepper motor driver board -- no lights
I have a ULN2003 stepper motor driver board and a 28BYJ-48 motor and I've got it working with an Arduino.
I use a separate power supply to power the motor.
When I connect it to the Arduino two of the four lights on the driver board come on.
But when I connect it to the Raspberry Pi Zero nothing comes on and I can't get it to work.
I'm using plain POSIX sh.
#!/bin/sh

#pins="17  27  22  23" # GPIO.
#pins="11  13  15  16" # Physical location.
pins="529 539 534 535" # Looked up from: cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio
delay=0.2

steps="1001 1000 1100 0100 0110 0010 0011 0001"

stepperStep() {
        for i in $( seq 4 ); do
                p=$( echo "$pins" | cut -d ' ' -f $i )
                v=$( echo "$1" | cut -c $i )
                echo "Write $v to pin $p"
                echo "$v" >/sys/class/gpio/gpio${p}/value
        done
}

stepperInit() {
        for p in $pins; do
                echo "$p" >/sys/class/gpio/export
                echo "out" >/sys/class/gpio/gpio${p}/direction
        done
}

stepperClear() {
        stepperStep "0000"
        for p in $pins; do
                echo "$p" >/sys/class/gpio/unexport
        done
}

stepperMove() {
        # param 1: number of steps
        neg=$( echo "$1 < 0" | bc )
        for i in $( seq $( echo "$1" | tr -d '-' ) ); do
                if [ $neg = 1 ]; then
                        j=$( echo "8 - ($i % 8) + 1" | bc )
                else
                        j=$( echo "($i % 8) + 1" | bc )
                fi
                s=$( echo "$steps" | cut -d ' ' -f $j )
                stepperStep "$s"
                sleep $delay
        done
}

if [ "$1" = "init" ]; then
        echo "stepperInit"
        stepperInit
elif [ "$1" = "clear" ]; then
        echo "stepperClear"
        stepperClear
elif [ ! -z $1 ]; then
        echo "init, move ${1}, clear"
        stepperInit
        stepperMove $1
        stepperClear
fi

Running stepper.sh init makes the symlinks appear at /sys/class/gpio and clear removes them again.
But I can't get any of the lights to come on or the motor to move.
Any ideas?
Update: wiring
This is the plan -- and I've double checked it.


Need clear photos of the wiring between driver board and Pi.

what do the lights indicate?

Add clear photos of the wiring.  Add the first sixty lines or so of the diagnostic output your script prints.  Use piscope to check the GPIO.

@jsotola these driver boards have a LED for each of the four stepper motor coils. They light if that coil is energised.
